# FirebaseListAdapter not pushing individual items for chat app - Firebase-Ui 3.1

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am making a chat app on Android that uses google firebase to store messages that users write to each other. To display these messages to the users I read them from the database and organize them into a custom ListView with a ListAdapter. This was working fine until I updated my dependencies, specifically firebase ui to:

```
com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.0
```

Now the code to construct the list adapter does not work, being:

```
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Lobbies").child(leaderID).child("Messages"), ChatMessage.class, R.layout.message, this) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };
```

To fix this issue, I updated the code to conform to the new firebase ui requirements, making the code become:

```
FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Lobbies").child(leaderID).child("Messages"), ChatMessage.class).setLayout(R.layout.message).build();

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };
```

This code compiles fine now, but the listview is not displaying the data. Is there a specific right way to use the new firebase ui dependency to make the list adapter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### To let the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and FirebaseListAdapter show the data on the activity

You need to use this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
adapter.startListening();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Since `FirebaseListAdapter` uses a listener to check for changes in the firebase database, then to being listening for data you need to add `adapter.startListening()` inside the `onStart()` to be able to show the data in the listview.

Then inside `onStop()` (when activity is stopped), you can use `adapter.stopListening()` to remove the listener and the data in the adapter.

Check this for more info: [Adapter LifeCycle](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle)

## Note:

If after using the above, you get a `nullpointexception` or `cannot resolve symbol`, you have to declare `adapter` as global variable and please check the below answer: [Error in startListening()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802581/error-in-firebase-android/47812129)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's been said in [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47228433/4916627), according to FirebaseRecyclerAdapater latest api [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md), you can create a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` passing in a `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` instance which is created by a builder. In the builder you specify a lifecycle owner so you don't have to modify either its `onStart` or its `onStop` manually:

```
private fun MainActivity.setUpFirebaseRecyclerAdapter():
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder> {

val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setQuery(ONLINE_USERS.limitToLast(10), User::class.java)
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .build()

return object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder>(options){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListOnlineViewHolder {
        return ListOnlineViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.user_layout, parent, false))
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListOnlineViewHolder, position: Int, model: User) {
        holder.bindMessage(model)
    }
}
}
```

The options builder is made up of a setQuery method which takes in a reference to the db and a model object; the setLifecycleOwner which takes in the activity that will trigger the adapter updates.