# Error in FirebaseListAdapter.startListening()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I've got a problem with my Firebase. When I debug my app i've got error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.startListening()' on a null object reference

Below is my code:

```
 private void displayChatMessage() {


    FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(""), ChatMessage.class).setLayout(R.layout.messages).build();

    ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // zdefiniuj elementy modelu

            TextView messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // ustaw wartosci
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

            // format daty pokazywanej w wiadomosciach
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
@Override
protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   adapter.startListening();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: is displaychatmessage method inside onCreate?

Comment: no , displaychatmessage is  inside  MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
 super.onStart();
 adapter.startListening();
}
```

Now `onStart()` is an activity lifecycle, and here you are starting to listen for values.

The activity life cycle is like this:

```
onCreate()>onStart()>onResume()
```

Those three methods are called so your activity appears infront of you. And since you are using `adapter` inside `onStart()`, then the initialization of the adapter needs to be in the method before it which is `onCreate()`. So this `adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {...}` has to be inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: please can you give a snippet code in how the code will be. i don't understand your answer.