# RecyclerView using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is not displaying items - FirebaseUI (3.1.3)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

i've been working on my application and i want to have a **fragment** that displays suggested **users** to follow (display some users from the data base `child("users")` but when i set up my `RecyclerView`,  no items (profiles) are displayed
so heres my layout for the fragment :

[image]

the `RecyclerView` is right under the Suggested Users.. its not showing any data,
here's my items XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            android:id="@+id/user_in_list_image"
            app:border_color="#fff"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:border_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="User203"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/user_in_list_username"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:text="El Eulma, Algeria"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                android:id="@+id/user_in_list_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <com.like.LikeButton
                android:id="@+id/user_in_list_followButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:icon_size="@dimen/_16sdp"
                app:is_enabled="true"
                app:icon_type="thumb" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.like.LikeButton
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:icon_size="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                app:is_enabled="true"
                app:icon_type="heart" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

here's my `Object Model` java.class :

```
public class User {
public String name;
public String gender;
public String birthday;
public String work;
public String country;
public String language;
public String city;
public String postal;

public User() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

public User(String name ,String gender, String birthday, String work , String country,String language , String city ,String postal) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.work = work;
    this.country = country;
    this.language = language;
    this.city = city;
    this.postal = postal;
}

public String getName() { return name; }

public String getGender() { return gender; }

public String getBirthday() { return birthday; }

public String getWork() { return work; }

public String getCountry() { return country; }

public String getLanguage() { return language; }

public String getCity() { return city; }

public String getPostal() { return postal; }

}
```

here's my `ViewHolder` java.class :

```
public class users_holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
private static final String TAG = users_holder.class.getSimpleName();
public TextView userName,userInfo;
public CircleImageView userImage;
public com.like.LikeButton likeButton;
public users_holder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    userName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_in_list_username);
    userInfo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_in_list_info);
    userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_in_list_image);
    likeButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_in_list_followButton);
}
}
```

here's my framgent.java `onCreateView` :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false);
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction("Discover");

    }

    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mUid = mUser.getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseref = mDatabase.getReference().child("users");
    suggestedRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.Suggested_users_recycler);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    suggestedRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
            .setQuery(mDatabaseref, User.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, users_holder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, users_holder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull users_holder holder, int position, @NonNull User model) {
                holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.userInfo.setText(model.getCity() + ", " + model.getCountry());
        }

        @Override
        public users_holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
            // layout called R.layout.message for each item
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.user_in_list, parent, false);

            return new users_holder(view);
        }

    };
    suggestedRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);




    return view;
}
```

What am i doing **wrong** ? i saw that other **versions** were just fine when u had to set up the **adapte**r in an external **class**, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Peter Hadad's** answer worked for me here:
>   [Android ListView adapter not pushing individual items for chat app - Firebase-Ui 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228262/android-listview-adapter-not-pushing-individual-items-for-chat-app-firebase-ui)
>   , so You need to use this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
adapter.startListening();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Since `FirebaseListAdapter` uses a listener to check for changes in the firebase database, then to being listening for data you need to add `adapter.startListening()` inside the `onStart()` to be able to show the data in the listview.
Then inside `onStop()`, you can use `adapter.stopListening()` to remove the listener and the data from the adapter.

Comment: Yeah thank its work.