# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not displaying data (in my case All users) from the database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In this On start method I am trying to display the List of all Users from the Firebase Realtime database, but it is not showing any users at all. No error on the Logcat.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                        .setQuery(mDatabase, Users.class)
                        .build();
        Toast.makeText(this, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users,useersViewholder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, useersViewholder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull useersViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Users model) {
                holder.setName(model.getName());


            }

            @Override
            public useersViewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                Toast.makeText(UsersActivity.this, "Inside  onCreateViewHolder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                View v=LayoutInflater.from(UsersActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.users_single_row,parent,false);
                return new useersViewholder(v);
            }
        };
        Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mUserList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);



    }
    public static class useersViewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View MItemView;

        public useersViewholder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            MItemView=itemView;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            TextView mUsername=MItemView.findViewById(R.id.users_DisplayName);
            mUsername.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47228433/7015400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I guess your problem is due to (not calling startListening on your adapter).

so under this line in onStart method:

```
     mUserList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

add this

```
     firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It works.perfectly fine

Comment: If this is the solution accept the answer so others know the problem?