# Unable to use custom layout in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In my blog app, post that include (title, description, and image). Unable to retrieve data from Firebase and show it using RecyclerView adapter. I am unable to identify the problem where it is. Code is:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mBlogList;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");

        mBlogList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Blog_Images");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Blog> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog>()
                        .setQuery(query, Blog.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>
                (options) {
            @Override
            public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_row,parent,false);
                return new BlogViewHolder(view);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BlogViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Blog model) {
                holder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                holder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                holder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());
            }
        };
        mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDescription(String desc)
        {
            TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
        {
            ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            //Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(image).into(post_image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PostActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My `MainActivity` is just blank. I don't know where is the problem.
I tried `ValueEventListener`, `addValueEventListener` but no result, in fact it says in LOGCAT:

> Unable to find layout, skipping this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView adapter not pushing individual items for chat app - Firebase-Ui 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228262/android-listview-adapter-not-pushing-individual-items-for-chat-app-firebase-ui)

Comment: also above .setQuery(query, Blog.class) write .setLayout(...) your layout

Comment: it says `unable to resolve setLayout` when writing it doesn't show any method setLayout.

Comment: remove this `mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);`

Comment: I removed that line, didn't worked though.

Comment: are the POJO variables the same as in your database?

Comment: yes, i have checked it many times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164043/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-anish-arya).

Comment: how to continue in chat? sorry, i am a newbie here

Comment: just click on `continue this discussion in chat` in my comment

Comment: @PeterHaddad ineed help, cant add post to the database, when clicked on submit button nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with OP in chat, he exported the JSON and the parent node had the name `Blog` and not `Blog_images`, so I told him to change this:

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Blog_Images");
```

into this:

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Blog");
```

Comment: thankyou so much for the help. i was stuck here for 7 days

Comment: hey there, i need your help in firebase again, when can we chat?

Comment: please ask it as a question and hope for the best, it is better maybe someone else can help you also

Comment: i am unable to retrieve image from my firebase database. i tried picasso and glide both, but unable to fetch image from database. no errors, gave internet permisssion, cant identify anything in logcat

Comment: please ask it as a question with code of the specific problem provided

Comment: help, cant add new post,items to database, when clicked on submit button, nothing happens