# If there is data in query or Path it show data in FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. but when there is no data at that path

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I use `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` with query. I show the loading till it's not getting into `onBindViewHolder()`. If it comes to `onBindViewHolder` then I close the dialog.

But in my scenario there is no data into query and its not get into  `onBindViewHolder` so I do not found anyway to close it. Here is my code. Please help.

```
Query query = GlobalApplication.applianceRef.whereEqualTo("applianceType", appType);

FirestoreRecyclerOptions < RoomAppliance > response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder < RoomAppliance > ()
    .setQuery(query, RoomAppliance.class)
    .build();

if (dialog != null) {
    dialog.show();
}

adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter < RoomAppliance, ApplianceActivity.ViewHolder > (response) {
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ApplianceActivity.ViewHolder holder, final int position, final RoomAppliance model) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public ApplianceActivity.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
        View view = null;
        try {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.user_appliance, group, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return new ApplianceActivity.ViewHolder(view);
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView adapter not pushing individual items for chat app - Firebase-Ui 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228262/android-listview-adapter-not-pushing-individual-items-for-chat-app-firebase-ui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got Answer

```
  @Override
                    public void onDataChanged() {
                        if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }

                        if(getItemCount() == 0){

                            remoteListRV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            msgTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            msgTv.setText("No "+ appType +" Available  !!!!");


                        }else {

                            remoteListRV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            msgTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }

                    }
```