# Firebase Recycler Adapter is not showing anything

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am making a fragment where i am showing some data in recyclerview. But it is not showing anything not event the error.
I am not using any @PropertyName of firebase
Here is my firebase database snap

[image]

### NewCustomer.java (my module class)

```
package com.example.lenovo.jdstudio;

import java.util.Map;

public class NewCustomer {
    private String fName, lName, email, phone, photodesc, status;
    private Map time;

    public NewCustomer() {}

    public NewCustomer(String fName, String lName, String email, String phone, String photodesc, String status, Map time) {
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.photodesc = photodesc;
        this.status = status;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getfName() {return fName;}

    public String getlName() {return lName;}

    public String getEmail() {return email;}

    public String getPhone() {return phone;}

    public String getPhotodesc() {return photodesc;}

    public String getStatus() {return status;}

    public Map getTime() {return time;}
}
```

#### Updaterder.java

```
public class UpdateOrder extends Fragment {

    private View mView;
    @BindView(R.id.customerDetailsRecyclerView)
    RecyclerView mCustmoerDetails;

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mCustomerDatabase;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mManager;
    private static final String TAG = UpdateOrder.class.getSimpleName();
    public UpdateOrder() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update_order, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,mView);

        mCustmoerDetails.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mCustmoerDetails.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        Log.e(TAG,"Before firebaseoption");

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mCustomerDatabase = mDatabase.getReference().child("new_customer");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NewCustomer> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<NewCustomer>().
                        setQuery(mCustomerDatabase,NewCustomer.class).
                        build();

        //        Log.e(TAG,"OnStart");

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NewCustomer, CustDetailHolder> (options){
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustDetailHolder holder, int position, @NonNull NewCustomer model) {
                holder.setFname(model.getfName());
                holder.setLname(model.getlName());
                holder.setPhotoDetail(model.getPhotodesc());
            }

            @Override
            public CustDetailHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.single_order_details, parent, false);
                Log.e(TAG,"oncreate is called");

                return new CustDetailHolder(view);
            }
        };
        mCustmoerDetails.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }

    //ViewHolder class
    public static class CustDetailHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;

        public CustDetailHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setFname(String  name) {
            TextView FName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.cust_Fname);
            FName.setText(name);
        }


        public void setLname(String name) {
            TextView LName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.cust_Lname);
            LName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setPhotoDetail(String photoDetail) {
            TextView photo_details = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.photo_Details);
            photo_details.setText(photoDetail);
        }

        public void setOrderSpinner(String status){

        }
    }


}
```

#### single_order_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cust_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cust_Fname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fname"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cust_Lname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:text="Lname"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cust_name"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:text="order Status goes here"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/order_status_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cust_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/order_status"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/order_status"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
            android:text="Photo Description:"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/photo_Details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_15dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
            android:text="4x6 id and passport"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

#### fragment_update_order.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.UpdateOrder">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customerDetailsRecyclerView">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks For seeing the post. waiting for the answer.
Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong.
dont't mark it duplicate without reading it.
I have attached all the listener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase @PropertyName doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work)

Comment: Also check this, another reason why adapter might not show anything: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228262/firebaselistadapter-not-pushing-individual-items-for-chat-app-firebase-ui-3-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in your database, your fields do **not** corespond to those from your model class. To solve this, delete the old data, add fresh one and your problem will be solved.

As I see in your code, you are using for the declaration of  your `CustDetailHolder` class, the `static` keyword, which is wrong. You only need:

```
public class CustDetailHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

Also remove `ButterKnife.bind(this,mView);` as I see that you don't use it in your code.

Comment: Ty for viewing i did the change as you said but it still not working .please see my question again

Comment: `ButterKnife.bind(this.mView);` is for the `@BindView`

Comment: Have you tried to remove the static keyword? Does it work?

Comment: yes i have did that change and run the  code but it still not working can you see that duplicate mark and tell me  acc. what should i do

Comment: What duplicate mark? Do you have an error? Or the `RecyclerView` remains empty?

Comment: No .some one has said that my question is same as this  question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681260/firebase-propertyname-doesnt-work)

Comment: We'll see later what is moderator opinion. In the mean while,Do you have an error? Or the RecyclerView remains empty?

Comment: it  remains empty. What i am seeing that it is not even printing the `Log.e(TAG,"On create is called")` from the `onCreateViewHolder()` it means that **adapter is having some problem .** But I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: does it because of Map?

Comment: One more question. Are you sure you don't have old records anymore? If you have, delete them and try again. So?

Comment: yes i have deleted the whole node and i inserted the new data from my add user fragment then also

Comment: I see in your error: `E/UpdateOrder: Fname null`. So there is somewhere left `Fname`. Find it, delete it and try again. So?

Comment: I have added a value event listener and try to deserialized the data by datasnaphot.getValue() and after that i printed this statement `Log.e(TAG,"fname"+cust.getFname)` thats why it is showing like that

Comment: I understand. Try to see my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846631/i-cant-see-any-firebaserecycleradapter-items-on-my-layout/48851402#48851402).

Comment: I had removed Map time variable and change the corresponding field now it is showing the data but only once i.e if i start it at first time it is showing the data but after first time if i re run the app it again giving the blank screen

Comment: Do you have an error when you start the second time?

Comment: Can you show me your entire code? Add a screenshot in your comment.

Comment: it worked hell yeah TY for all the support and  bearing with me [ Source ](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/204) removed the  `setHasFixedSize(true)`

Comment: You're welcome! Good to hear that it worked! If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: also you think my question can help some one else upvote it. Most welcome

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same problem as you described, thank you for sharing the problem and comments. I followed them and found out that I should remove setHasFixedSize(true) from the recycler view. Also, I should override the onStart and onStop methods with start and stop listening for the adapter, respectively. That has solved my problem of **not showing anything on recycler view**.

P.S: I am aware that you have found your answer and solved your problem long ago. I am just sharing this conclusion here as it was not directly extractable from the discussion.

Comment: solved my problem. setHasFixedSize(true) was the problem there.

Comment: Thanks @bikalpa yes setHasFixedSize was the issue. Almost broke my head 1 hour to fix this

Answer (score 0):

The strings in your model class:

```
fName
lName
```

must be the same as in your database, in your database you have this:

```
FName
LName
```

## For Anyone Checking this:

It was solved as I said in my comment:

> @Aakash keep it, but put this instead mCustmoerDetails.setHasFixedSize(false) – Peter Haddad yesterday

OP had to add `mCustmoerDetails.setHasFixedSize(false)` instead of `mCustmoerDetails.setHasFixedSize(true)`

or remove `mCustmoerDetails.setHasFixedSize(true)`

Comment: @Aakash please try my answer

Comment: my model class is having the same name please look again

Comment: kk i am trying your answer

Comment: I have added a value event listener and then i print the log it is showing me null value as follows `D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x62995160 sslRead buf=0x423a8da0 len=1,timeo=0
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -L5n7VYRTA-2vgojwfhg found on class com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.NewCustomer
E/UpdateOrder: snapshot DataSnapshot { key = new_customer, value = {-L5n7VYRTA-2vgojwfhg={time=1519128808600, photodesc=I'd passport, phone=9028847184, lName=vidlan, status=placed, email=aakashbidln@gmsil.com, fName=aakash}} }
E/UpdateOrder: Fname null`

Comment: You need to change the Fname to fName @Aakash

Comment: i have changed that only please see the image of database again

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.lenovo.jdstudio, PID: 22231
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
` it is giving this error

Comment: @Aakash keep it,  but put this instead `mCustmoerDetails.setHasFixedSize(false)`

Comment: still giving the same error i think it is bcoz `Map time` variable

Comment: @Aakash why did u choose his answer as correct and i told u to remove `sethasfixedsize(true)` in the previous comments

Comment: Sorry i don't mean to hurt you thanks to you also for helping me a lot and step given by him has also helped me you both help me unfortunately due to my low reputation i can't upvote your ans.. sorry bro

Comment: It is fine, not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Man maybe your forgot to call
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening in your @override onStart(){}

Comment: and firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening() in @override onStop