# My application not retrieving data from firebase child node

Tags: android, firebase

This is my code:

When I am running this code unfortunately your app stopped error is showing.

Not showing error in Android Studio only the app is crashing.

I think I'm getting in setting the reference.

```
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
   import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;
   import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
   import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
   import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

 public class FoodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
 private RecyclerView mRecycler;
 private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);
    String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    Toast.makeText(this, "select "+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mDatabaseRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("item/1");
    mRecycler=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFood);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food,foodViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, foodViewHolder>(
            Food.class,R.layout.food_list,foodViewHolder.class,mDatabaseRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(foodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {
           viewHolder.setfname(model.getfname());
           viewHolder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
}

public static class foodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public foodViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        mView= itemView;
    }
    public void setfname(String fname){
        TextView tvFood=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvFood);
        tvFood.setText(fname);
    }
    public void setPrice(int price){
        TextView tvprice=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.fprice);
        tvprice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please post at least a photo of your database, we dont know if your reference is orret or not if we dont see the database structure

Comment: kelo copy paste, chi b 2aref sayra hal tag!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cant see any FirebaseRecyclerAdapter items on my layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846631/i-cant-see-any-firebaserecycleradapter-items-on-my-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to retrieve data you should do this in your `onStart()`

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

What it does

> The FirebaseRecyclerAdapter uses an event listener to monitor changes
>   to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call the
>   startListening() method. You may want to call this in your onStart()
>   method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to
>   read the data before calling startListening() or your query will fail.

and in your `onStop();`

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}

Similarly, the stopListening() call removes the event listener and all data in the adapter. Call this method when the containing Activity or Fragment stops
```

Edit: make your adapter global

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food,foodViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;
```

and then in your `onStart();` change this

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food,foodViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, foodViewHolder>(
            Food.class,R.layout.food_list,foodViewHolder.class,mDatabaseRef....
```

to this

```
mFirebaseAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, foodViewHolder>(
            Food.class,R.layout.food_list,foodViewHolder.class,mDatabaseRef...
```

hope it helps

Happy coding !