# unable to retrieve data from one app to another app from firebase single Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 applications(different package names) which use one Firebase database. One app has to write access to the database and another have read access to the database.in my second application, i use recyclerview to retrieve data which is stored by 1st App.

**for this I use below code:**

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:567....259c8f58311") // Required for Analytics.
            .setApiKey("AIzaSyA9BRxl......hE03y5qD-c") // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://mycity-3a561.firebaseio.com/") // Required for RTDB.
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "MyCity");
         // Retrieve my other app.
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("MyCity");
          // Get the database for the other app.
    FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
    DatabaseReference data = secondaryDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {

                    WaterClass waterClass = dSnapshot.getValue(WaterClass.class);

                    Log.d("Show", waterClass.getName() == null ? "" : waterClass.getName());
                    list.add(waterClass);

                }
                adapter = new WaterAdapter(ShowWaterDetails.this, list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

**Adapter class**

```
  private class WaterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WaterAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ShowWaterDetails showDetail;
    List<WaterClass> listData;

    public WaterAdapter(ShowWaterDetails showWaterDetails, List<WaterClass> list) {

        this.showDetail = showWaterDetails;
        this.listData = list;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.show_items, parent, false);
        WaterAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new WaterAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WaterAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        WaterClass AllDetails = listData.get(position);
        holder.NameTextView.setText(AllDetails.getName());
        holder.DetailTextView.setText(AllDetails.getDetail());
        holder.DateTextView.setText(AllDetails.getDate());
        holder.LocationTextView.setText(AllDetails.getLocation());
        holder.TypeTextView.setText(AllDetails.getType());
        Picasso.with(showDetail).load(AllDetails.getImgurl()).resize(120, 60).into(holder.ImageTextView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return listData.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView NameTextView;
        public TextView DetailTextView;
        public TextView DateTextView;
        public TextView LocationTextView;
        public TextView TypeTextView;
        public ImageView ImageTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            NameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowNameTextView);
            DetailTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowDetailTextView);
            DateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowDateTextView);
            LocationTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowLocationTextView);
            TypeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowTypeTextView);
            ImageTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowImageView);

        }
    }
}
}
```

**POJO Class**

```
class WaterClass {

private String id;
private String email;
private String name;
private String type;
private String detail;
private String location;
private String date;
private String imgurl;

public WaterClass(){
}

public WaterClass(String id, String currentUserString, String imageUrl, String nameString, String typeString, String detailString, String locationString, String dateString) {

    this.id = id;
    this.email = currentUserString;
    this.name =nameString;
    this.type = typeString;
    this.detail = detailString;
    this.location = locationString;
    this.date = dateString;
    this.imgurl = imageUrl;
}

public String getImgurl() {
    return imgurl;
}

public void setImgurl(String imgurl) {
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}

public void setDetail(String detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

}
```

**[image: Database Structure]:**

there is no error but my recycler not showing anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView adapter not pushing individual items for chat app - Firebase-Ui 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228262/android-listview-adapter-not-pushing-individual-items-for-chat-app-firebase-ui)

Comment: can you post a pic from your firebase database?

Comment: Btw you are using an old firebase version

Comment: soo, that is the problem?

Comment: I doubt it, but it is still better if you update firebase

Comment: is this appearing in the Log `Log.d("Show", waterClass.getName() == null ? "" : waterClass.getName());`?

Comment: it shows nothing

Comment: try this `String date=dSnapshot.child("date").getValue().toString(); Log.d("Show date: ", date);`

Comment: okay, let me try

Comment: But I think it is better to just use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: String date=dSnapshot.child("date").getValue().toString(); Log.d("Show date: ", date); this says variable are not available

Comment: in my other app,recyclerview worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution!!
just change this part of a code

```
  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "MyCity");
     // Retrieve my other app.
  FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("MyCity");
```

TO

```
   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
      // Retrieve my other app.
   FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("[DEFAULT]");
```

Answer (score 1):

go to onStart() and start listening

```
   @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

and in your onStop

```
    @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses a snapshot listener to monitor changes to the Firestore query. To begin listening for data, call the `startListening()` method. You may want to call this in your `onStart()` method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling `startListening()` or your query will fail.

> Be sure that the names of constant in the POJO match exatly the names
>   of your database structure in your firebase console !!

ps: do not post your api-keys or app-ids in your questions, keep them secret, and consider using `firebaserecycleradapter` if you are using firebase-database , it will be more easy to setup and to show values.

Your POJO is ok !

Comment: he is using a normal recycler view not firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: he is not using firestore

Comment: PS: startListening() and stopListening() only apply to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and FirebaseListAdapter not normal listview and normal recyclerview

Comment: yes, i know, i think its gonna be better for she to implement the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to show the data.

Comment: yes I mean the answer does not solve anything until now