# Output not showing when the firebase ui upgrade to 3.2.2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

When i upgrade my firebase-ui version to 3.2.2 the firebaserecycleradapter doesn't show any output the code of mine. at first when i got multidex error then i upgrade all library version to lastest version on dependency of app lvl gradle and after upgrade the problem is found the Firebaserecycleradapter method then i search it and write after run the app the list view are not displaying plz help me.

onStart():

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions <Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                .setQuery(mUserDatabase,Users.class)
                .build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.user_list_layout, parent, false);
                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Users model) {
                holder.setName(model.getName());
                holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
                holder.setRIDNo(model.getRidno());
                holder.setUserImage(model.getThumb_image(), getApplicationContext());

                //to get key
                final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(UsersActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                        startActivity(profileIntent);

                    }
                });
            }

        };
        mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
```

and the viewholder is:

```
//User list viewholder
    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        static View mView;
        private CircleImageView mUserView;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public static void setName(String name){
            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);
        }
        public static void setStatus(String status){
            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(status);
        }
        public static void setRIDNo(String ridno){
            TextView userRIDNoView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_ridno);
            userRIDNoView.setText(ridno);
        }
        public static void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){
            CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your code work, please consider using the following steps.

1. Remove the `static` from the declaration of your `UsersViewHolder` class. Should be only:

   ```
   public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {/* ... */}
   ```
2. Remove the `static` keyword also from the `mView` field and all your methods. Your holder class should look like this:

   ```
   public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       private View mView;
       private CircleImageView mUserView;

       public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           mView = itemView;
       }

       public void setName(String name){
           TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
           userNameView.setText(name);
       }
       public void setStatus(String status){
           TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
           userStatusView.setText(status);
       }
       public void setRIDNo(String ridno){
           TextView userRIDNoView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_ridno);
           userRIDNoView.setText(ridno);
       }
       public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){
           CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
           Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Move all the code from the `onStart()` method inside onCreate() method except this line of code:

   ```
   super.onStart();
   ```
4. Make your `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` varaible global:

   ```
   private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
   ```
5. Remove `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>` from the onCreate() method.
6. Add the following lines of code in the `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       if(firebaseRecyclerAdapter != null) {
           firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
       }
   }
   ```
7. If you are using authentication, please also don't forget to add this line of code inside `onStart()` method:

   ```
   firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
   ```

Comment: sir i can't clear in step 5 can u explain me and sry for late response sir

Comment: Thanks sir it's work for me i know what is wrong on my code thank you so much sir @Alex

Comment: You're welcome and happy to hear that it worked. Cheers!