# Spinner not populating from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner, firebaseui

With the code below there are no errors but the data is not displaying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a beginner and don't know how to fix this.

It would also be great if code for this solution could be provided.

```
public class AddReviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner companyNameSpinner;
    ArrayList<String> companies = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_review);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Company");
        companyNameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.companyNameSpinner);
        DatabaseReference mref = databaseReference.child("name");

        FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mref) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
                ((TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model);
            }
        };
        companyNameSpinner.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
    }
```

[image: Firebase Data]

Comment: Are you calling `adapter.startListening()` anywhere? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228262/firebaselistadapter-not-pushing-individual-items-for-chat-app-firebase-ui-3-1/47228433#47228433

Comment: Have you tried to use `new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, databaseReference)?`

Comment: It wont work because the childs are not String, however using thad node it is correct

Answer (score 0):

In the [doc](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview) the builder is recommended

```
//Please notice Im using databaseReference and Company
//More details further
FirebaseListOptions<Company> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Company>()
        .setQuery(databaseReference, Company.class)
        .setLifeCycleOwner(this);
        .build();
        //Frank van Puffelen coment is right, you have to start listening some how
```

You can't

```
mref = databaseReference.child("name");
```

And expect to get a list of the companies names, is not equivalent to SQL `select column`

You need to create a POJO representing the Company

```
public class Company {

    private String name;
    //TODO other attributes
    //TODO getters and seters
    //TODO default constructor
}
```

And now you can initialize the adapter:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<Company> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Company>(options) {...
```

When you try to set the data to the row using the *general* `findViewById` won't work because your adapter is an inner implementation of an abstract class, you are accessing the `Activity` parent method. **You have to use the View**.

```
protected void populateView(View v, Company model, int position) {
TextView tv = (TextView) view;
view.setText(model.getName());
}
```

I don't know if this is supposed to work with a `Spinner` is ment for `ListView`.

For further growth you have to learn how to debug, in this case the first step would be to add a log inside the `populateView` method

```
Log.d("COOL_TAG", model);
```